# I am trying to convert SQL to Query DSL i want join 2 tables User table and News table to find who is post most blog

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl

Here is the original sql
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BI6Y.png)

I tried to conver to query dsl but it just not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlfSU.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need querydsl-sql
[github link:](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-sql)